# Electric shock from pellet stove

Tags: electrical, wiring, concrete, stove

I accidentally let some hot pellets fly out of my pellet stove while stupidly cleaning the glass while it was on. The few pellets melted some of the carpet. I put them out with some water. When i went to try and pick them out of the carpet I leaned my hand on the stove a received a good shock. My pad under the carpet is solid concrete. After a bit of trial and error I found that I do not receive a shock while touching anything dry. I unplugged the stove and still received a shock. I pulled up some of the carpet and there is no wiring under the carpet. What could this possibly be?

Comment: Was it a static shock (single sharp snap), or an electric shock (sustained pulsating jolt)?

Answer (score 3):

- ***I'd really stop testing this by shocking yourself.***  (!)
- If it happens repeatedly it's usually not static.
- If it happens more when you're on water, probably not static.

You can use a non contact voltage tester (NCVT) to see if the stove frame is energized:

[image: Santronics NCVT]

Just don't trust it too much, and test it on an outlet every time you use it to make sure it's working.

I'd use the NCVT to verify that the frame of the stove is energized, unplug the stove (carefully!) and test again.

If it's hot plugged in but OK unplugged, I'd call whoever installed or services the stove, otherwise call an electrician.

Comment: It takes pretty good juice to get a shock through damp concrete. I've gotten a tingle from 120v, and that is not something you want to mess with using your body once you find out the problem exists. A little better conduction is all it'll take to kill you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting voltage when unplugged, check whether the chimney -- or its mounting hardware -- have contacted wires somewhere. You may have to play with circuit breakers and do some partial disassembly to isolate this.